# iPhone/iPad Viewport issues

Tags: html, ios, css, media-queries, viewport

I have been trying to get into responsive design recently. The only problem I have come across so far is the viewport stuff on the iPad and iPhone.

When I set the Initial-Scale to 1 it seems to double the page size on the iPhone (retina) even if the media query is set to width 640px. Note that the media queries are working fine as far as I can see, everything adjusts as it should. I can fix the double zooming problem by either double tapping to zoom out every time the page loads or by setting the initial-scale to 0.5. The problem with setting it to 0.5 is that when you view it on the iPad it's half the size of the screen. 1.0 seems to work on the iPad but seems to double it up on the iPad (The iPad and iPhone have separate media queries).

*Summary*: Scale 1.0 on the iPhone doubles the page zoom, fine on iPad. Scale 0.5 fine on iPhone, half the size on the iPad.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Just a question, what happens when you take out the `initialScale` property?

Comment: @Jon The problem seems to go away. But when you go from portrait to landscape it zooms all by itself, is that an iOS bug/feature though? If the user scaling was turned off, it would mean that the site would stay zoomed when rotated.

Comment: @TheTechBox this rule from [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/2.0.1/normalize.css) may be useful for you: `/* Prevents iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling user zoom. */` `html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

There is a media query for "pixel ratio" so that you can target higher resolution devices:

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}
```

Also, are you setting `width=device-width` in the viewport meta tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Will targeting the higher resolution devices work for the iPad (pre-retina)?